# What does DATE OF EVENT mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

Who knows the meaning of DATE OF EVENT in the following passage? I thought it might mean a particular day, but why it follows FROM EVENT START TIME TO EVENT END TIME which seems like a period of time between two particular days. I`m confused.

> This contract serves as an agreement between [Client] and [Vendor]. It becomes effective on [Date] and involves services provided for [Event], which will be held on [Date of Event] from [Event start time] to [Event end time].

Comment: held on Saturday from 3pm to 5pm? what's the problem?

Comment: Now it seems like a very simple sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's a contract that covers someone providing services to another party for a set period of time, starting at one date and time and finishing at another. To flesh it out with a made-up example:

> This contract serves as an agreement between ABC Parties and DEF Catering. It becomes effective on 19 January 2017 and involves services provided for Alan's birthday party, which will be held on 23 January 2017 from 21:00 to 23:30.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is my first time asking question in this website, you guys are very obliging.

Comment: @LarryWang - no problem at all; I've heard English is very difficult for non-native speakers to master. I'd say you're doing very well :-)

Answer (score 1):

A date is a date, and a time is a time.

"Date of event" means the date the Event is to be held on. The event runs between its start time and its end time **on that date.** The first "[Date]" in that sentence is the start date of the *contract itself* and that will probably be before the date of the event, in order to cover preparations up to the event.

As a picture is worth a thousand words, here's a filled-in version:

> This contract serves as an agreement between *John Smith* and *Acme Catering.* It becomes effective on *19 January 2017* and involves services provided for *The wedding of Miss Suzy Smith,* which will be held on *21 January 2017* from *12 noon* to *8:00pm.*

Comment: I was confused with the concepts of DAY and Time ( mixed with the concepts of Chinese words), silly of me. Thank you anyway.